# Ble Scanning Devices Android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am scanning BLE devices.
Here is my code;

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



private boolean mScanning;Button ara ;
ListView lw;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
private Handler mHandler;
private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;
private BluetoothLeScanner mLEScanner;
private ScanSettings settings;
private List<ScanFilter> filters;
private BluetoothGatt mGatt;
private ArrayList<String> deviceListesi = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> mDeviceStore = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayAdapter<String> deviceAdapter ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mHandler = new Handler();
    if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "BLE Not Supported",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
            (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    lw = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    ara = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    deviceAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, deviceListesi);
    mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
    ara.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            scanLeDevice(true);
        }
    });
}
private final BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, final byte[] scanRecord) {
        System.out.println("Buradayım mmmmmmmmmmmm");
        final String deviceIsim = device.getName()+" "+device.getAddress();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),deviceIsim,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mDeviceStore.add(deviceIsim);


        for (final String leDevice : mDeviceStore) {
                deviceListesi.add(leDevice);

        }

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               lw.setAdapter(deviceAdapter);

            }
        });
    }
};
public void scanLeDevice( final boolean enable) {
    if (enable) {
        if (mScanning) {
            return;
        }
        Log.d("TAG", "~ Starting Scan");
        // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.

            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d("TAG", "~ Stopping Scan (timeout)");
                    mScanning = false;
                    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                }
            }, SCAN_PERIOD);

        mScanning = true;
        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    } else {
        Log.d("TAG", "~ Stopping Scan");
        mScanning = false;
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }
}
```

}

I have list view but nothing to happen ? this is the android monitor prints;

> D/TAG: ~ Starting Scan  D/TAG: ~ Stopping Scan (timeout) 
>   D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()  D/BluetoothAdapter: scan not started
>   yet

Where am i wrong to do ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: I am debugging my code no errors, no not working functions. I cannot resolve my question.

Comment: And what has your debugging session taught you?

Comment: I set breakpoint scanLeDevice, that function working correctly. And i set breakpoint onLeScan function in LeScanCallBack.the code never arrive this function. I have BLE device i tested my device with one playstore app and i found it so my device is working.

Answer (score 0):

Remove line

```
mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
```

Bluetooth LE and "old" bluetooth are different things. You can't mix the two.

Comment: I remove it but still continue